# Background images won't load dynamically

Tags: html, angular, image

I'm trying to set the background image of a div dynamically using Angular 6...
But for some reason no matter what I do, It seems I can't make the image to render.
The images are being served from a local SimpleHTTPServer using python.

HTML:

```
<a *ngFor="let movie of movies">
    <div [style.background-image]="movie.image">
        {{movie.name}}
    </div>
</a>
```

Component:

```
getMovies() : void {
    this.movieService.getMovies().subscribe(movies => this.movies = movies.map(movie => {
        movie.image = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(`url(${movie.image})`);
        return movie;
    }));
}
```

I've tried also using the sanitizer with no success... And i'm not getting any errors.

Answer (score 1):

You can use like this:

```
<a *ngFor="let movie of movies">
    <div [ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url(' + movie.image + ')'}"> {{movie.name}}</div>
</a>
```

or

```
 [style.backgroundImage]="'url('+ movie.image +')'"
```

Updated:
You should also mention height and width in div as mentioned by [user184994](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2780943/user184994) in comment section like this:

```
<div [ngStyle]="{backgroundImage: 'url(' + movie.image + ')', width: '200px', height: '150px'}"></div>
```

Comment: @user3763577 You need to make sure that the `div` is styled to have a height and width as well, otherwise it will be 0px

Comment: Seems to work? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sdhxge?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html I'm guessing the issue is to do with the `/img/` that you're prepending to the URL

Comment: When I i'm using some image from google it works...
But when I use the image that is being served it doesn't work

Comment: @user3763577 Okay, are you able to create a StackBlitz or something that reproduces the issue?

Comment: did you look this code https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sdhxge?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the url is URI Encoded.
In JS: encodeURI(url)